# Showing fixed point existence for a particular expansion mapping

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

I'm working through a problem very similar to [Fixed point for expansion mapping.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661013/fixed-point-for-expansion-mapping), I started on a different path to the accepted answer and wasn't able to solve it that way. But it *feels* like I'm close. Is it possible to solve the problem this way and if so how?

**The problem is:** Given a Banach space $X$, a constant $K > 1$ and a mapping $T$ on $X$ satisfying
\begin{equation}
||T(x) - T(y)|| \ge K ||x - y|| \qquad \forall\, x, y \, \in X \,, \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Assuming $T(X) = X$, show that $T$ has a unique fixed point.

**My attempt at a solution** Let $(z^0_n)$ be any Cauchy sequence in $X$. $z^0_n \rightarrow z^0 \in X$ since $X$ is complete. Since $T(X) = X$, we have that for all $n = 1, 2, \ldots $ there exists $z^1_n \in X$ such that $z^0_n = T(z^1_n)$. Furthermore, $\exists z^1 \in X$ such that $z^0 = T(z^1)$.

\begin{equation}
||z^0_n - z^0|| = ||T(z^1_n) - T(z^1)|| \ge K ||z^1_n - z^1||
\end{equation}

Since $z^0_n \rightarrow z^0$ we get $z^1_n \rightarrow z^1$. We can continue inductively to show that these limits exist to form a sequence $(z^m)$. By iteratively applying (1) iteratively we get for any $n$

\begin{equation}
||z^{0} - z^{n}|| = ||T(z^1) - T(z^{n + 1})|| \ge K ||z^1 - z^{n + 1}|| \ge K^m ||z^m - z^{m+n}|| \\
\implies \frac{1}{K^m}||z^{0} - z^{n}|| \ge ||z^m - z^{m+n}|| \,. \tag{2}
\end{equation}

Since $||z^0||$ and $||z^n||$ are finite, we get that $||z^m - z^{m+n}||$ can be made arbitrarily small with $m$ large enough. Therefore $(z^m)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $X$, and $z^m \rightarrow \tilde{z} \in X$. This also means that $T(z^m) \rightarrow \tilde{z}$.

**From here I imagined** that it would be easy to argue that $T(\tilde{z}) = \tilde{z}$ and prove that the fixed point exists, but I haven't been able to. Is it at all possible to continue from here to show the desired result?

Comment: Take $w$ such that $T(w) = \overline{z}$. What do you know about $\lVert z^m - w\rVert$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it thanks to the hint by Daniel Fischer:

---

Take $w \in X$ such that $T(w) = \tilde{z}$. From the property of the mapping we get

\begin{equation}
||T(z^m) - \tilde{z}|| = ||T(z^m) - T(w)|| \ge K ||z^m - w|| \,.
\end{equation}

Since LHS $||T(z^m) - \tilde{z}|| \rightarrow 0$ we get $z^m \rightarrow w$. By uniqueness of limits, $w = \tilde{z}$. Now from $w$'s definition

\begin{equation}
\tilde{z} = T(\tilde{z})\, .
\end{equation}

Finally, uniqueness is shown by taking any $v \in X$ such that $v = T(v).$ Then

\begin{equation}
||v - \tilde{z}|| = ||T(v) - T(\tilde{z})|| \ge K ||v - \tilde{z}|| \implies ||v - \tilde{z}|| = 0 \,,
\end{equation}

so the fixed point $v = \tilde{z}$ is unique.  $$\tag*{$\Box$}$$